# i can't read json in ionic 5

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

i work in inoic 5 / angularjs project this app get data from api and display it

(1) this function to get data from api :

```
getProdects(){
    this.categoryId   = this.activatedroute.snapshot.params["id"];
    console.log(this.categoryId);   
  this.presentLoading();
  this.apiservice.getdate("posts/cat/5").subscribe(data => {
     //this.posts = JSON.parse(data.data);
     console.log(data);
     this.loadingController.dismiss();
      return this.posts = data;
  })}
```

(1) and this html code :

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor = "let post of posts" >
    <ion-thumbnail>
        <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/{{ post.image }}" alt="have error" >
    </ion-thumbnail>    
    <ion-label>{{ post.title }}</ion-label>
    <p></p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

display this error in browser:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

and array show like this :

```
{2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}}
```

---

```
2: {id: 4, title: "ثلاجة الجي 14 قدم", body: "ثلاجة علوية 14 قدم مكعب رمادي داكن", image: "images/KZbWKFnJgFR4njb97kZSblwa96zv367yUqXAttx9.jpeg", image2: "images/xbuSDXSq0XUCnPuZKTREJRr7Fkay6nMAnKpRuxcw.jpeg", …}
```

---

```
3: {id: 5, title: "ثلاجة توشيبا سعة 355 لتر", body: "ثلاجة توشيبا نوفروست سعة 355 لتر ، 2 باب لون سيلفر مزودة بيد دائرية", image: "images/ID4A1mK42KxSie6uZRkdMhmSXkOXy2uj7XkWJinm.jpeg", image2: "images/HEtOn8gqx60bfbpxR2i6qVNTHaLJtn7UfgiEtU53.jpeg", …}
```

---

```
4: {id: 6, title: "ثلاجة سامسوج بابين", body: "ثلاجة سامسوج بابين - نوفورست سيلفر", image: "images/U3ONmUmq8S3kMJZ4VgmVLWLOBAFlWugOkew7Ndx3.jpeg", image2: "images/NDGQLs0S1GNZlZkO8ZYIoW5034KXtctPRbuBJLen.jpeg", …}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Kind of you need to convert string to JSON, no? Try to do something like `JSON.parse(stringified json)`

Comment: @MaximShoustin Angular's HTTP library by default trasforms response data with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `data` variable is of `object` type and not an `array`, so when you assign it to `return this.posts = data`, `this.posts` now becomes an object. You can do the following to make it into an array

```
this.posts = []
for(let key in data){
    this.posts.push(data[key])
}
return this.posts
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your HTML with this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor = "let post of posts | keyvalue" >
    <ion-thumbnail>
        <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/{{ post.value.image }}" alt="have error" >
    </ion-thumbnail>    
    <ion-label>{{ post.value.title }}</ion-label>
    <p></p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

That's it!

Comment: @AbdoMograt Thank you, my friend. if one day you used Observables use " | async" or " | async | keyvalue" instead. and upvote the answer if possible.